Yocto build failed due to permission denied due to failed execution flags when build in shared folder
My environment:

Mac M2
MacOS Sonoma 14.5
Lima VM
Docker
User inside docker is build with groups build,adm,sudo,disk

I have a repository containing yocto's poky checked out to ${HOME}/project/maxrepo.
I run my docker container this way: docker run --name=maxcontainer -it -v ${HOME}/project/maxrepo:/maxrepo:rw maxdocker:latest /bin/bash to build poky inside.
In case my build folder is placed in the shared folder /maxrepo inside the docker I get the error:
> cd /maxrepo
> source poky/oe-init-build-env
> bitbake core-image-minimal

Sstate summary: Wanted 1867 Local 0 Mirrors 0 Missed 1867 Current 0 (0% match, 0% complete)#######################################################################################                  | ETA:  0:00:00
Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: m4-native-1.4.19-r0 do_patch: Applying patch 'ac_config_links.patch' on target directory '/max-os/build/tmp/work/aarch64-linux/m4-native/1.4.19/m4-1.4.19'
CmdError('quilt --quiltrc /max-os/build/tmp/work/aarch64-linux/m4-native/1.4.19/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push', 0, 'stdout: 
stderr: /bin/sh: 1: quilt: Permission denied
')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /max-os/build/tmp/work/aarch64-linux/m4-native/1.4.19/temp/log.do_patch.1567
ERROR: Task (/max-os/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.19.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'

because quilt does not get the execution flags. But I can do chmod a+x quilt for that file.
But if I do the same in the home dir in the docker container, everything is fine.
Whats the issue with the docker container to allow the yocto build to set the right permissions during build?

I face the same problem at the moment only difference is i've tried running it with podman instead of docker
